# sharey='all' argument in plt.subplots() not passed to df.plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe which I would like to slice, and plot each slice in a separate subplot. I would like to use the `sharey='all'` and have matplotlib decide on some reasonable y-axis limits, rather than having to search the dataframe for the min and max and add offsets.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50).reshape((5,10))).transpose()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=0,ncols=0, sharey='all', tight_layout=True)

for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,i)    
    iC = df.iloc[:, i-1]
    iC.plot(ax=ax)
```

Which gives the following plot:
[image]

In fact, it gives that irrespective of what I specify `sharey` to be (`'all'`,`'col'`,`'row'`,`True`, or `False`). What I sought after using `sharey='all'` would be something like:
[image]

Can somebody perhaps explain me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plots are not shared. You create a subplot grid with 0 rows and 0 columns, i.e. no subplots at all, but those nonexisting subplots have their y axes shared. Then you create some other (existing) subplots, which are not shared. Those are the ones that are plotted to.

Instead you need to set `nrows` and `ncols` to some useful values and plot to those hence created axes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50).reshape((5,10))).transpose()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=3, sharey='all', tight_layout=True)

for i, ax in zip(range(len(df.columns)), axes.flat):
    iC = df.iloc[:, i]
    iC.plot(ax=ax) 

for j in range(len(df.columns),len(axes.flat)):
    axes.flatten()[j].axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at least I get why it dosen't work now. I moved away from specifying nrows, ncols as that tended to leave empty plots. Is there a function/parameter where one can add plots dynamically and still having sharey behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The following version would only add those axes you need for your df-columns and share their y-scales:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50).reshape((5,10))).transpose()

fig = plt.figure(tight_layout=True)

ref_ax = None
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, i+1, sharey=ref_ax)
    ref_ax=ax
    iC = df.iloc[:, i]
    iC.plot(ax=ax) 

plt.show()
```

The grid-layout Parameters, which are explicitly given as `...add_subplot(2, 3, ...` here can of course be calculated with respect to `len(df.columns)`.